# Django how to give a user input for writing email text

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a template for sending custom emails:

[image]

The template is as below:

```
<p> Type here your email: </p>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ mail_content }}">

{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Send the Request  " name="_add_peer_confirm">
<input type="submit" value="Go back to Standard Email  " name="_">
<input type=button value="Go back" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
</div>
```

How can I make it tidy and gives the user a longer/elongated input box where he can write his mail?

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a larger input box, then you could use [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

```
<textarea id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name">{{ mail_content }}</textarea>
```